# Fetch Data from SQL Database (No MYSQL DB) (in android) using JSON with PHP

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried the following code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();//Warning in this line Explicit type arg <> diamond 
        getData();
    }
```

but I get this warning in this line

`personList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();`

Comment: okay i will try and why my layout cloud not display data?? in my logcat northing show

Comment: need to set Adapter for ListView to show data

Comment: actually i declare  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> personList;  this line but same error

Comment: which warning getting?

Comment: Explicit type arg <> diamond

Comment: Does my solution works? Do you need any more help?

Comment: i set Adapter for ListView @ρяσѕρєяK  'ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                    new int[]{R.id.cus_id, R.id.cus_Name, R.id.cus_city}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);'

Comment: Please edit your question instead, code is not readable in comment XD.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Do you need any more help?

Comment: yes i got it thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 1):

Replace your

```
personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

line to

```
personList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: wait i will check it out

Comment: yes the warning gone. but i cont get data in my list. when i run my php json to hold the data but android cloud not  display

Comment: well your question were about the warning. How do you try to fetch the data :)?

Comment: i think that the warning is problem now its gone but i can not get values okay no problem i will try

Comment: how is your getData() function looks like bro? If you need more help please share more info or if your problem is solved please mark my answer accepted. Thanks

Comment: sure bro done done